# Prewitt edge detector implemented with Matlab gives thick edges than the in-built function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I implemented the Prewitt edge detector and compared my output with Matlab's in-built Prewitt edge detector and I noticed that my output gave thicker edges. What could be the reason?

```
input = imread('pic.png');
input = double(rgb2gray(input));
kernel_x = [-1, 0, 1; -1, 0, 1; -1, 0, 1];
kernel_y = [1, 1, 1; 0, 0, 0; -1, -1, -1];

[length, width] = size(input);
new = input;
for i = 1:length - 2
  for j = 1:width - 2
    Gx = sum(sum(kernel_x.*input(i:i+2, j:j+2)));
    Gy = sum(sum(kernel_y.*input(i:i+2, j:j+2)));
    new(i+1, j+1) = sqrt(Gx.^2 + Gy.^2);
  end
end
new = uint8(new);

% binarizing image and setting threshold
edge = imbinarize(edge, 100); % final output from implementation
```

The in-built function I used is `edge(input, 'Prewitt')`
Output from my implementation vs the in-built operator:

[image: comparison of two results]

What could be the reason for this?

I tried changing the Threshold value also but still no luck.

Comment: I think it's the `edge(edge==100) = 0` line.  I think you want to use `<` instead of `==`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I used Matlab edge() function. edge(input, 'prewitt')

Comment: @DrewHall I changed my code. Instead of using 3 lines for thresholding, I used imbinarize(edge, threshold). Still, I g0t thick edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clearly stated in the documentation, but for the Sobel, Prewitt and Roberts methods, `edge` applies a thinning. There is [an optional input argument `'nothinning'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html#d123e91824), which skips the thinning step. Unfortunately this is the only bit in the documentation that indicates that this step is happening.

You can apply a thinning if you have the Image Processing Toolbox using `bwmorph(bw,'thin')`.